¿Como puedo Cambiar la Ruta de Destino de un Acceso Directo con CMD o Python?
]1
Con Batch o Python quiero cambiar la ruta de "Destino" del acceso directo de forma automatizada para un proyecto de Ciberseguridad.
Hay algún comando en Batch (CMD), o libreria en Python que me pueda ayudar a realizar una modificación sin que el usuario se de cuenta?
Ayuda, esto es un proyecto que tengo que entregar el 06/08/2024 para Universidad!

This question is similar to: ¿Como puedo Cambiar el Path de un Acceso Directo con batch o Python?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Si bro, es básicamente la misma. He estado investigando desde hace dias y nada que logro dar con la respuesta. Ando un poco agobiado.

¡No repitas preguntas! Ten presente que [es.so] es una base de conocimientos, no un foro donde se responde a preguntas urgentes. De hecho: Bajo qué circunstancias puedo agregar "urgente" o frases similares a mi pregunta para obtener respuestas más rápido? y Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero.
